# thread sanitizer is not showing data race

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, debian, clang

I tried the program given [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html#usage)

small_race.c

```
#include <pthread.h>
int Global;
void *Thread1(void *x) {
  Global = 42;
  return x;
}
int main() {
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, Thread1, NULL);
  Global = 43;
  pthread_join(t, NULL);
  return Global;
}
```

compilation

```
$ clang -fsanitize=thread -g -pthread -O1 small_race.c
$./a.out  ==> No error it's passing successfully
```

I tried to create 2 more thread and also try to sleep in one of thread then also it's passing. I am using Debian OS

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your platform or installation. With your exact code, I get:

```
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=20087)
  Write of size 4 at 0x000000601080 by thread T1:
    #0 Thread1(void*) /tmp/a.cpp:4 (a2+0x000000400a7f)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x0000000235b9)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x000000601080 by main thread:
    #0 main /tmp/a.cpp:10 (a2+0x000000400ac5)

  Location is global '<null>' of size 0 at 0x000000000000 (a2+0x000000601080)

  Thread T1 (tid=20089, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000027a67)
    #1 main /tmp/a.cpp:9 (a2+0x000000400abb)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /tmp/a.cpp:4 Thread1(void*)
==================
```